# Как использовать id чекбокса для изменения цены?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня в БД для каждого ингредиента есть своя цена, я могу вывести их сумму человеку, но мне надо чтобы если чекбокс отключен, цена этого ингредиента вычитывалась, как это сделать?

```
            <?php
                  }
                }
              }if(isset($_POST['Pepperon'])){
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Ingredient` WHERE id_ingr = '2'";
                if($result = $conn3->query($sql)){
                  $count = 0; 
                  foreach($result as $row ){
                    $count++;
                    $ingredient = $row['ingredient'];
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $price += $row['price'];
                    
              ?>
                 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"  name ="checkboxx[]" value="<?php echo($ingredient); ?>" id="checkbox<?php echo($id); ?>" checked/>
                 <label class="label" for="checkbox<?php echo($id); ?>"><?php echo($ingredient); ?> </label>
                 
              <?php
                  }
                }
              }
              ?>
```